# python DFT inaccuracy

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, precision

I am trying to implement a DFT in python

but i sometimes get some inaccuraciesin the trig. functions due to the nature of floating point
is there an easy solution to this problem or an easy change to my code which minimises the inaccuracies?
whats my best option here?

my Code:

```
def DFT(values) :
    N = len(values)
    out = list()
    for n in range(N):
        real = 0
        imag = 0
        for i, value in enumerate(values):
            phi = (2 * math.pi * n * i) / N
            real += value * math.cos(phi)
            imag -= value * math.sin(phi)
        real = real / N
        imag = imag / N

        freq = n
        amplitude = math.sqrt(real * real + imag * imag)
        phase = math.atan2(imag, real)
        out.append((freq, amplitude, phase, real, imag))
    return out
```

is it appropriate to use the decimal module?
and to use the sin and cos aproxiomations described here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-recipes

Comment: Show sample input, observed output, and the output desired instead. Make it clear what inaccuracies you observe.

Answer (score 0):

A common source of "some inaccuracies in the trig. functions" is not due to "the nature of floating point", but that `math.pi` is not π, just a value near it.  This manifests when `phi` is well outside the primary range
[-π/4...π/4] (or [-45°...45°]).

Code can help by reducing `2 * n * i) / N` to the [-1...1] range using modulo math so the angle is in the [-π...π] range.  Thus the range reduction is exact, rather than via `math.pi`.

I suspect that with Python (I do not have strong Python skills), it would be:

```
f = ((n * i) / N) % 2.0
if (f > 1.0) f -= 2.0
else if (f < -1.0) f += 2.0;
phi = math.pi * 2.0 * f
```